# How to make code::blocks choose the newer version of GCC

Tags: gcc, code-blocks

I have Code::blocks 13.2 which uses GCC version 4.8.2,but recently I install the latest GCC version which is 5.How Do I make CB use the latest version of GCC 5?.

I desperately want to use the C++14 features which is not found in GCC 4.8.2.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't there a setting somewhere like Settings->Compiler and Debugger->Global Compiler settings->Toolchain executables?

Comment: tried but not working.